# How to check for duplicate values in an array and return the index in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm making a Battleship game, and in order to test for if two ships are overlapping I made two arrays, one containing all the X position of the blocks the ships occupied, and one contains all the Y position.

I need to somehow know if there are duplicate values in my arrays, and know the index that these duplicates happens. I looked up some of the solutions here, but none works. They mostly contained sort, but sorting changes the order of the values in the array. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Are the X and Y positions floats or ints?

Comment: Why don't you show your code and then we might be able to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a code to find duplicate elements in an array :

```
arr = [1, 1 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 1 , 5];

for ( i = 0; i < arr.length -1 ; i ++){
    for (j=i+1; j < arr.length; j++ ){
        if (arr[i] == arr[j]){
            console.log("Current element" + arr[i]);
            console.log("initial index:" + i);
            console.log("index:" + j);
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to compare with another array:

```
arr = [1, 1 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 1 , 5];
arr2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 2];

for ( i = 0; i < arr.length ; i ++){
    for (j=0; j < arr2.length; j++ ){
        if (arr[i] == arr2[j]){
            console.log("Current element" + arr[i]);
            console.log("initial index:" + i);
            console.log("index:" + j);
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: He wants to find the duplicates and their corresponding indices from the arrays, right ?

Comment: Sorry, it was too strong, it's certainly not completely irrelevant - but he seems to want duplicates of x and y coordinates from two arrays, so you'd have to compare whether `x[i]` *and* `y[i]` are both same as `x[j]` and `y[j]`.

Comment: @Amadan Oh. Okay. My bad. But nevertheless I feel , he can modify this code to suit his needs. It was not clear from his question, what he exactly wanted, so I posted two answers.